# Multiple problems with twitter bootstrap - toggling tooltips, non-responsiveness

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

http://dynamo.viralsmods.com/becky

The circular images of people on the front page have a tooltip associated with them. When you hover over each tooltip for the first time, it shows, but any subsequent hover does not. What is the reason for this?

Secondly, if you view the website on a smaller screen (either mobile or just shrink your screen), the navbar shows the three lines instead of the links. When you click/ tap the three lines, it brings up a dropdown menu with the new links. When you tap it again to hide it, it hides and then automatically shows again. This error seems to be the same sort of problem with the tooltips, as it can't show/hide properly.

Any insight?

Answer (score 1):

http://dynamo.viralsmods.com/becky/web/js/jQ.min.js (included in your page) is jQuery **v1.7.1**.

Bootstrap [requires jQuery **>=1.9.0**](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/8a6a253355ab1d26865bfbfffaa2a194e173a3aa/bower.json#L36)

Upgrade your jQuery!

Comment: Just what I was about to say!